# How to use matlab to take texts from certain excel cells?

Tags: excel, matlab

I am trying to use Matlab code to copy phone numbers from column G of an excel file (Data.xls). Then put them into an array named MP.

So I used this code:

```
[num,text,raw]=xlsread('C:\Documents and Settings\Data.xls',1,'G:G');

MP=text
```

It works but the empty columns are also included. This is the output:

```
MP=
'+12345678'
'+12323423'
'+14323434'
''
''
'+12323233'
''
'+15435455'
''
'+18493348'
```

What to do to make the empty columns not included? Any idea? Thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for each element in MP if it is not empty, then use the resulting logical vector to index MP.

```
MP=MP(cellfun(@(x)not(isempty(x)),MP))
```